# Enum internationalization exception

Tags: java

I have an enum and I tried to internationalize it like:

```
public enum ActivityEnum {
PROJECT_CREATED, PROJECT_EDITED, PROJECT_DONATION;

@Override
public String toString() {
    switch (this) {
    case PROJECT_CREATED:
        return Messages.get("activity.project.created");
    case PROJECT_EDITED:
        return Messages.get("activity.project.edited");
    case PROJECT_DONATION:
        return Messages.get("activity.project.donation");
        default: return super.toString();
    }
}

private ActivityEnum activityEnum;

public ActivityEnum getActivityEnum() {
    return activityEnum;
}

public void setActivityEnum(ActivityEnum activityEnum) {
    this.activityEnum = activityEnum;
}
```

}

Now, please note that the keys defined in my messages.properties contains string formatters like:

```
activity.project.created = User <%s> created project <%s>
```

Well, the issue is that when I do something with this enum in other places in the code, it throws an exception like:

```
MissingFormatArgumentException occured : Format specifier 's'
```

so basically it wants that when I get the key in `toString` enum class, to apply also the args for formatting but this I only do later where I use that enum...

```
activity.summary = String.format(activityEnum.toString(), args);
```

Can you please give me a suggestion of how to handle this?

**UPDATE**:

If I use the classic way, all works nice:

```
PROJECT_CREATED("User <%s> created project <%s>"), PROJECT_EDITED(
        "User <%s> edited project <%s>"), PROJECT_DONATION(
        "User <%s> made a donation of <%d> to project <%s>");
```

but this is without internationalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- pass the key in the constructor and store it in a member field
- write a method like:

  public String toDisplayString(String... args){
   ...
  }
- get rid of the switch statement